# ModuleNotFound error in Django. Not able to resolve error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I don't understand the error. I made a same project earlier but was facing some problems with virtualenv so I made another directory with virtualenv and just copy pasted all the codes in the all the files including manage.py settings.py and urls.py. I started app with command line in virtualenv and copy pasted all codes from previous app.

manage.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():

    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'quicktt.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output(error)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 8, in main
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE')
TypeError: setdefault() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
(quicktt) udaykhalsa@warmachine:~/Projects/quick_timetable_main$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quicktt.settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/Projects/quick_timetable_main/quicktt/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quicktt.settings'
```

Comment: What is the name of your new Django application?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami project name is quick_timetable and app name is web_home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'quicktt.settings')
```

to

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'quick_timetable.settings')
```

Django is trying to find the `settings.py` file inside `quicktt` which does not exist because this is a new Django project, and the settings file is inside `quick_timetable`.

Comment: Solved. There were many quicktt wods which I had to replace with quick_timetable. My previous project name was quicktt. Should've kept that in mind.